# VPN Certificate Validation Failed (OpenVPN)? CentOS & Ubuntu

Tags: certificate, vpn, centos

Ok, I'll explain what I did... and at the end is the queston. THank you!

To set up my VPN I installed OpenVPN in server and client machines. On server I configured the cert Authority in the file /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/vars editing this lines:

```
export KEY_COUNTRY=”ES”
export KEY_PROVINCE=”M”
export KEY_CITY=”Madrid”
export KEY_ORG=”My Organization”
export KEY_EMAIL=”mail@example.com”
```

then i generated the cert:

> cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/ ln -s openssl-1.0.0.cnf openssl.cnf source
>   vars ./clean-all ./build-ca

Created the cerver certs:

> ./build-key-server myServer

Diffie Hellman parameters to server

> ./build-dh

Copyed certs and keys /etc/openvpn

> cd keys/
>   cp myServer.crt myServer.key ca.crt dh1024.pem /etc/openvpn/

Created client Certs

> cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
>   source vars
>   ./build-key client1

Copied this certs to client machine and erased them from server:

> /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
>
> /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/cliente.crt
>
> /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/cliente.key

Edited /etc/openvpn/server.conf to my files names

```
ca ca.crt
cert myServer.crt
key myServer.key
dh dh1024.pem
```

> /etc/init.d/openvpn restart

Verified that tun0 is there

> ifconfig tun0

Enabled ip_forward parameter on /etc/sysctl.conf  so packages may flow

> net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Also enabled virtual network masking so client may access all remote machines

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

and saved the ip tables conf so they dont desappear in a reboot

Save conf into file

> sudo sh -c “iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules”

Edit /etc/network/interfaces adding the interface (eth0 in this case)

> pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules

Getting the following server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb3
```

In the client i installed OpenVPN and edited the client.conf file which is in /etc/openvpn with the certs: ca.cert, client1.key, client1.conf getting the following client.conf file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

then restarted:

> /etc/init.d/openvpn restart

And when i want to verify that the interface tun0 is there with ifconfig tun0, there is not.

So I checked my log for errors, in the client machine and there is this error:

```
VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=unable to get local issuer certificate: /C=Es/ST=M/L=Madrid/O=xxx/OU=xxx/CN=myServer/name=xxx/emailAddress=mail@xxxx.co
TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
user openvpn[7984]: TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
user openvpn[7984]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

and this is the error int the servers log

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59439 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
MULTI: multi_create_instance called
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59485 Re-using SSL/TLS context
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59485 LZO compression initialized
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59485 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59485 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59485 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '530fdded'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59485 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '41690919'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59485 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59485, sid=0349f4d6 657535c9
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59440 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59440 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59440 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

I've created the keys again, and added the full path of the certs in the client.conf file but it still doesn't work. Also tryed with all my firewalls disabled and still cant conect to my server because of that error.

> Another important thing is that my server is an ubuntu 12.04 and client CentOS 6.3

I can see that i find my server but still the connection isn't completed...

What should I do??

If any more config files are needed, tell me to show you

Comment: What's the server configuration?

Comment: ok here it is. I added it to the question

Comment: Your posted server configuration appears to have the key and cert pointing to the client key/cert.

Comment: Sorry. Finger error.. Let me correct..

Comment: Don't delete the client keys off the server.

Comment: Anything on server-side logs?

Comment: Nope.. nothing on the server-side

Comment: and I didn't delete the client keys .. they are in `/etc/openvpn` and also in `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys`

Comment: wait... i found something on the servers log... i'm going to update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error message indicates that the client doesn't like the certificate presented by the server for whatever reason.  Send a copy of server.crt to the client, then run:

```
openssl verify -purpose any -CAfile ca.crt server.crt
```

If it's OK, you should get something that looks like `server.crt: OK`

Basically, you want to check that the server.crt is properly signed by the ca.crt file on the client.  You can play with the options to see what a failure looks like by leaving out the `-CAfile ca.crt`.  In this case (or if the ca.crt did not sign the server.crt) you will get some message like:

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

If this is the case, go over your certificate generation process.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very usefull answer... I did get the message you say `error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate`so i'm going to create the certs again.. What is the best method to create them? Is it ok with RSA scripts? .. or what can you recommend me? ..

Comment: And another thought that is bothering me from the beggining... is it ok to create the client certs in the servers and then send them to the client? or should I create the client certs in the client machine? does it matter??

Comment: The easy-RSA scripts should be fine.  You can run `openssl` directly, but that can be tricky.  For your second question, it depends on your security policy.  If you control both end points and the transit (i.e., using ssh/scp), then I would just create everything on the server and send the client files over.  If you have a stricter situation, you can have the client generate a proper certificate signing request, send that to the server, generate a certificate off of it, and send the cert to the client. In this case, the private key doesn't leave the client. Might be overkill, though.

Comment: Thank you a lot! ..very useful.. still having troubles =S .. but with this I'm closer..

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. The problem was that I was using the ca.crt that easyrsa generated. This is wrong. Use the cacert.pem in /etc/ssl/misc/demoCA/ instead.